# how could make a function which accept dynamic number of arguments?

Tags: php, function, arguments

My doubt is, how could I make a function which can accept dynamic number of arguments? For example

in the case of `setcookie()`

```
setcookie("TestCookie",$value);
```

is accepting only two values and set the cookie. And the same function

```
setcookie("TestCookie",$value, time()+3600*24);
```

which accept 3 parameters. And

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600*24, '/', NULL, 0);
```

will also work.

How could I make it possible in my own functions?

Comment: there is already fixed args in setcookie() if you not send then will be null values

Comment: @RakeshSharma, Thank you for the information. so `function sample($arg1 = NULL, $arg2 = NULL)` will do the trick??

Comment: `function myFunction($param1, $param2='default', $param3=null)` http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-171 Example #4-6

Comment: you can use array this can hold multiple values like cookie. Generally  cookie, server, session, get and post values are superglobal array

Comment: @Arun may be my answer more clear

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). Try harder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass an array to function for this like

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,3,4); //pass any number of values

function myfunction($arr) {
}
```

Or you define more variable to null at function initialize like

```
function myfunction($param1= '', $param2='', $param3='') //set null to default
```

calling:-

```
myfunction('',2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help... LEt me check with this.. :)

Comment: this works perfect. Thank you. I Tried with `function add_multi($a, $b, $c=NULL,$d=NULL){return $a+$b+$c+$d;}`